# How to add the output of a for loop inside a for loop to a list of lists? Python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, montecarlo

I am trying to output the result of (Monte Carlo paths) calculations done in a for loop inside a for loop to a list of lists. However, I only get one list. I have indicated below several things I tried.

The result I get is:
`[path1]`

What I expect is: `[[path1], [path2], ..., [path100]]` Where every `path` should be a list of `steps` values starting at `s0`.

Any suggestions?

```
num_reps = 100
s0 = 10
steps = 6

def func(num_reps, s0, steps):
    for j in range(num_reps):
        paths = [s0]
        st = s0
        for i in range(int(steps)):
            st = st*np.random.normal(0, 1)
#            paths.append(st)
#            paths.append([st])
#            paths = steps[steps.index(i):]
        return paths
    return ''
a = func(num_reps, s0, steps)
```

Comment: `path1` should be a list of `steps` values starting at `s0`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Thanks have added this to the question.

Comment: you can use 'yield' and write a generator

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'yield' and write a generator

```
def path_generator(num_reps, s0, steps):
    for j in range(num_reps):
        path = [s0]
        st = s0
        for i in range(int(steps)):
            st = st*np.random.normal(0, 1)
            path.append(st)
        yield path

for path in path_generator(num_reps, s0, steps):
    print path
```